# Need to find names on one table and add the assigned value to all cells matching that name in another table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA, been working on this task where I have a table on Sheet1 with a list of names and numbers assigned to them:

```
Name    Number
A       5
R       4
T       6
Y       2
```

And another table in Sheet2 with the names as headers and lots of values to each column:

```
A   B   R   W   Y
10  40  70  10  40
20  50  80  20  50
30  60  90  30  60
```

I need to find all the names in the first table and add the number to all the values for that name on the second table, the result would be this:

```
A   B   R   W   Y
15  40  74  10  42
25  50  84  20  52
35  60  94  30  62
```

Tables are in the hundreds of names so this is not very easy to do with formulas. Any ideas on where to start using macros/VBA?

Comment: There are entire books available on *where to start using macros/VBA*. Your question is too vague and broad in scope. Also, SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. You'll have much better experiences here if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages before you start posting

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. You can do it with [Vlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and [Iferror](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) functions.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite ,  I'll try the approach provided by Dharman below and see if I can make the question more clear.

Comment: Hi @Naresh , I was adding a column and using Vlookup and it's working OK, but since the tables are too big (need to add for hundreds of names), I was looking for a more reproducible solution.

Comment: @darkideon, the question is closed for need of details. You can edit and reopen the question and wait for appropriate answer. ..Or .. [you can upvote / accept GGG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can learn from it but not just copy it.

I assume your Excel table should be like this (Value start from Cell A2 and B2):

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Number |
| A | 5 |
| R | 4 |
| T | 6 |
| Y | 2 |

Here is the code with comment:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim col As String
Dim CellName As String
Dim addnumber As Double

'First, you need to count the number of rows of column A with non-empty value
'       and hence you can assign the value to variable one by one using For Loop

For i = 0 To ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").Cells.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1

    'col = A,R,T,Y during this loop
    col = ws.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value
    
    'addnumber = 5,4,6,2 during this loop
    addnumber = ws.Range("A2").Offset(i, 1).Value
    
    'CellName = A1,R1,T1,Y1 during this loop
    CellName = col + "1"
    
    'Skip to do addition (Example: Column "T" does not contain value)
    If ws2.Range(CellName).Value <> "" Then
    
       'Same logic as mention above
       For j = 0 To ws2.Range(CellName, ws2.Range(CellName).Cells.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1
       
        'do addition
        ws2.Range(CellName).Offset(j, 0).Value = ws2.Range(CellName).Offset(j, 0).Value + addnumber
        
       Next
       
    End If
Next

End Sub
```